# ReactJS Syntax Error: Unexpected Token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am getting the Unexpected Token on my ReactJS application. But I believe the syntax is correct.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Auth extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            authStatus: "Sign In",
            isAuthenticated: false
        }
    }
    AuthMe = () =>{
        console.log("Working")
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <button type="button" onClick={this.AuthMe}>{this.state.authStatus}</button>
        );
    }
}

export default Auth;
```

ERROR in ./src/components/Auth/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (11:11)

```
> 11 |     AuthMe = () =>{
     |            ^
  12 |         console.log("Working")
  13 |     }
```

What am I missing?

### UPDATE

Here's my webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
      ],
      loader: 'babel-loader',
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.json', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015","react","stage-0"],
    "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

Comment: can you show how you configure your webpack

Comment: Sure gimme a second

Comment: @SaurabhSharma .babelrc ?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Updated

Comment: Downvoter, your valuable feedback will help

Comment: Can you try and include the babelrc plugins and presets in the webpackpack as `{
    "presets": ["es2015","react","stage-0"],
    "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}` . I think it is not picking up the .babelrc contents somehow

Comment: Did you try to move your babelrc contents to webpack

Comment: Yes i did tried that earlier

Comment: So your code is definitely valid, compiles fine in the [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/). Looks like something to do with your webpack config. - Can you show me your file structure? package.json as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class Auth extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            authStatus: "Sign In",
            isAuthenticated: false
        }
    }
    AuthMe() {
        console.log("Working")
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <button type="button" onClick={this.AuthMe}>{this.state.authStatus}</button>
        );
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** `AuthMe` is not just a regular function and not a fat-arrow function, if that matters to you.

### EDIT (after comment)

Using fat-arrow functions as class functions is not standard ES6 syntax ([the proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields) is stage-2 at the moment), so you will need an [additional babel plugin](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) to add the feature.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31362350/6902543) for more details.

Comment: I am going to `setState` in the `AuthMe()` that's why fat arrow to avoid bind

Comment: simply add the bind. I don't understand why people are so against adding a binding line, it's MUCH better to add a binding line than to rely on some stage-2 proposals.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question before here: [Arrow Function syntax not working with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063854/arrow-function-syntax-not-working-with-webpack/42064325#42064325)

TLDR Is that that fat arrow is not yet in the ES201whatever standard. You'll need to add an additional babel transform.

`npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`

EDIT: saw your babelrc config above, run the above then change .babelrc to

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015","react","stage-0"],
    "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-class-properties"]
}
```

Comment: That comes in stage-0 as well

Answer (score -2):

> use var AuthMe or const AuthMe instead of AuthMe

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class Auth extends React.Component {
        constructor(){
            super()
            this.state={
                authStatus: "Sign In",
                isAuthenticated: false
            }
        }
        var AuthMe = () =>{
            console.log("Working")
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <button type="button" onClick={this.AuthMe}>{this.state.authStatus}</button>
            );
        }
    }

    export default Auth;
```

Comment: I don't think that will make any difference