# reactjs Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i've created reactjs app with react-redux,redux.
when starting reactjs project, getting unexpected token error at line 13 on index file.
the index file is given beloow.

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: D:/Reactjs_work/
/src/index.js: Unexpected token (13:2)

  11 |
  12 | ReactDOM.render(
> 13 |   <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
     |   ^
  14 |     <App />
  15 |   </Provider>
  16 |   , document.querySelector('.container'));

 @ multi main
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

following is index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

i've gone through following topic over here.but no success.
[Reactjs: Unexpected token '<' Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905227/reactjs-unexpected-token-error)
[ReactJS Syntax Error: Unexpected Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867515/reactjs-syntax-error-unexpected-token)

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel'
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

Comment: Do you have `.babelrc` file?

Comment: Are you setting presets inside `.babelrc` ?

Comment: as i'm new to reactjs, don't know much about it.i downloaded project from https://github.com/RoadToCode822/react-side-projects and try to make it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace module with following code

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',

        query: {
           presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
    }]
  },
```

Comment: This should be a comment on the question, not an answer.

Comment: Now I have Edited my answer, Hope this helps. I could not comment since am new to this community of stack!!!!

Comment: @https.tejassdotin: Much better - switched my downvote to an upvote :)

Comment: @https.tejassdotin: I've upvoted, from now onwards you can comment :)

Comment: where do i add this in a rails-react project? I Didnt find any webpack-config or .babelrc file in the project

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (11:1)

   9 | 
  10 | ReactDOM.render(
> 11 |  <Provider store={store}>
     |  ^
  12 |      <App />
  13 |  </Provider>,
  14 |  mountNode

 @ multi main
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Me don't help the change of the module section.

My error: a missing .babelrc file

After creating .babelrc with content:

```
{
    "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"]
}
```

my error disappeared. So simple :-)