# Pass script src into Pug template

Tags: javascript, express, pug

I'm trying to get my Pug template to render a script using Express. My file structure is as follows:

```
views
    public
        index.jade
        main.js

index.js
```

I have tried passing the name of the script as an argument to `res.render('public/index', { bundle: '/main.js' })` with no luck.

Contents of my `index.js`:

```js
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views/public')));

app.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('public/index', { bundle: '/main.js' });
});
```

Contents of my `index.jade`:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title SSR React
    body
        div#root
        script(src='#{bundle}')
```

I'm getting a strange error in the console. The name of the script is coming through, but I'm getting the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

The contents of `main.js` when I look at the console are as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>SSR React</title></head><body><div id="root"></div><script src="/main.js"></script></body></html>
```

so, just the minified HTML which is being transpiled from Pug.

Can anyone shed some light here? Am I configuring Express incorrectly? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

While writing inline JavaScript in Jade template you need to add a dot after the script tag. Also you should indent your code.

For example include external js like:

```
script(type='text/javascript', src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
```

Inline js like:

```
script(type='text/javascript').
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Jade, but your Express setup is fine.  You can see from the rendered HTML that Express is passing the correct value into your template, i.e. '/main.js'.  You also know the bundle file is being served since you see it in devtools under 'sources'.  The error you're seeing is almost definitely a problem with your transpiled/bundled React code.  See [ReactJS: unexpected token '<'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53957787/reactjs-unexpected-token) for some steps you might try.

Answer (score 1):

easy!

```
include TOP.pug
head
  script(type='text/javascript').
    function ExampData() {
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://"blah.com:6789");
    ws.onopen = function() { ws.send("hola); };
    ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    // code comments like this are OK.
    el.innerHTML = e.data + "<br>" + el.innerHTML;
    };
    ws.onclose = function() { console.log("ws closed ..."); };
    }
| Example:
br
pre#logtag
br
| (Recent items are at the top)

script(type='text/javascript').
  var el = document.getElementById("logtag");
  ExampData()
```