# Getting error : src/react_header/src/index.js: Unexpected token (10:2) in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using webpack.

When I try run my app i am getting below error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /var/www/oxygen/src/react_header/src/index.js: Unexpected token (10:2)

   8 | 
   9 | ReactDOM.render(
> 10 |   <App title={title} />,
     |   ^
  11 |   document.getElementById('app')
  12 | );
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true
  }
};
```

It seems like the JSX isn't getting compiled by Babel, but I have the `babel-loader` in my Webpack rules.

Can anyone please look my code and help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you tried this https://www.robinwieruch.de/minimal-react-webpack-babel-setup

Comment: yes i used the same

Comment: did you installed all the packages that are required, are you including react-dom in index.js, add your entire index.js file

Comment: yes i installed all the pakckages which are required

Comment: try this one to add it in babelrc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53957787/reactjs-unexpected-token