# Running ❯ npm run dev Failed to compile with 1 errors Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, laravel, npm

So I keep running into this blocker. Not sure why this started or how to fix it. Any ideas as to what the solution could be? I've tried a number of things like `npm update` and flushing the node_module folder.

Node: v14.4.0
NPM: 6.14.4

package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
    }
}
```

error:

```
❯ npm run dev

> @ dev /Users/lucas/Sites/lm
> npm run development


> @ development /Users/lucas/Sites/lm
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

98% after emitting SizeLimitsPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors (<-this is the output npm gives, not a typo)                                      8:33:35 AM

 error  in ./resources/js/component/App.js

Syntax Error: SyntaxError: /Users/lucas/Sites/lm/resources/js/component/App.js: Unexpected token (9:12)

   7 |     render () {
   8 |         return (
>  9 |             <BrowserRouter>
     |             ^
  10 |                 <div>
  11 |                     <Header />
  12 |                 </div>
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './Header'

class App extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Header />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

**UPDATE**:
Note, I've already read the link below and the solution proposed does not fix the problem I'm experiencing: [ReactJS: unexpected token '<'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53957787/reactjs-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for me was finally found here:
https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8655#issuecomment-419808044

Adding in the following snippet into the package.json file stopped all unexpected (experimental) character type errors.

```
...
"babel": {
        "presets": [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            "@babel/preset-react"
        ],
        "plugins": [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
        ]
    }
...
```