# vue webpack uglify - arrow functions

Tags: webpack, vue.js, uglifyjs, arrow-functions

When building a Vue project including arrow functions, webpack's UglifJsPlugin gives this error:

```
Unexpected token: operator (>)
```

example:

app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import HelloWorldComponent from "./HelloWorld.vue";

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
  ,render: r => r(HelloWorldComponent)
});
```

HelloWorld.vue

```
<template>
    <div>{{message}}</div>
</template>

<script>
const data = { message: "Hello World" }
export default {
    data() { return data }
}
</script>
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require("path");
const HtmlPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");

const output = {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'app.js'
};
const vueLoaderRule = {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader'
};
const uglifyJsPlugin = new UglifyJsPlugin({
    include: /\.js$/,
    minimize: true
});

module.exports = {
    entry: './app.js'
    ,output: output
    ,module: {rules: [ vueLoaderRule ]}
    ,plugins: [ uglifyJsPlugin ]
}
```

note: my question was marked as duplicate of this:
[Arrow Function syntax not working with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063854/arrow-function-syntax-not-working-with-webpack)
1) it has nothing to do with Vue
2) it is about using arrow functions as class member, wheres my question is not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow Function syntax not working with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063854/arrow-function-syntax-not-working-with-webpack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, `UglifyJsPlugin` doesn't support ES6 feature (arrow function) so you must use babel first to compile your ES6 code to ES5 then use UglifyJsPlugin in it

Comment: How can I use babel with vue-loader?

Comment: First, you have to install `babel-loader` and create its config. Then in your webpack config, create new rule for `js` to use `babel` (you doesn't need to edit vue-loader config because it will auto-detect the presence `babel-loader` and use it