# Arrow functions not working inspite of babel

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, arrow-functions

I am trying to setup a project using loopback 4 and when I write an arrow function, it gives this error. It seems that the es6 code isn't being converted back to es5, hence the arrow function error. I've tried deleting all babel dependencies and trying it again, still it doesn't work.

```
executeStep = () => {
            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

I'm using babel 7 for this project.

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "applicationName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "applicationDescription",
  "keywords": [
    "loopback-application",
    "loopback"
  ],
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.9"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "esmodules": true
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "lb-tsc && babel src -s -d dist",
    "build:watch": "lb-tsc --watch",
    "clean": "lb-clean dist *.tsbuildinfo",
    "lint": "npm run prettier:check && npm run eslint",
    "lint:fix": "npm run eslint:fix && npm run prettier:fix",
    "prettier:cli": "lb-prettier \"**/*.ts\" \"**/*.js\"",
    "prettier:check": "npm run prettier:cli -- -l",
    "prettier:fix": "npm run prettier:cli -- --write",
    "eslint": "lb-eslint --report-unused-disable-directives .",
    "eslint:fix": "npm run eslint -- --fix",
    "pretest": "npm run clean && npm run build",
    "test": "lb-mocha --allow-console-logs \"dist/__tests__\"",
    "posttest": "npm run lint",
    "test:dev": "lb-mocha --allow-console-logs dist/__tests__/**/*.js && npm run posttest",
    "docker:build": "docker build -t orchestrator .",
    "docker:run": "docker run -p 3000:3000 -d orchestrator",
    "migrate": "node ./dist/migrate",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "node -r source-map-support/register . && nodemon --exec npm run babel-node -- ./index.js",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run test"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "files": [
    "README.md",
    "index.js",
    "index.d.ts",
    "dist",
    "src",
    "!*/__tests__"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@loopback/boot": "^1.5.5",
    "@loopback/context": "^1.22.1",
    "@loopback/core": "^1.10.1",
    "@loopback/openapi-v3": "^1.9.6",
    "@loopback/repository": "^1.13.1",
    "@loopback/rest": "^1.18.1",
    "@loopback/rest-explorer": "^1.3.6",
    "@loopback/service-proxy": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.0",
    "@loopback/build": "^2.0.10",
    "@loopback/eslint-config": "^4.0.2",
    "@loopback/testlab": "^1.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^10.14.17",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.1.0",
    "blue-tape": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.3.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-eslint-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-mocha": "^6.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.13",
    "typescript": "~3.6.2"
  }
}
```

Here's my babel.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
  plugins: [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions"
  ]
}
```

and here's the piece of code that's giving me the error

```
executeStep = () => {
    //some steps
}
```

Here is the error log

```
 executeStep = () => {
                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
```

Comment: Are you sure you need an equal to there? If this function is defined inside an object then its a colon that must be used, like this: let objFunctions = { executeStep: () =>{} }

Comment: This is a function inside a class. This is how it is defined in ES6

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the same, then have you tried the keyword 'this'? while declaring the function?

Comment: It doesn't work that way

Comment: Are you sure the Babel config is being used? Is the file throwing the error in `node_modules` by chance? Are you sure Babel is actually set up to run in whatever context you're using this code in?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
var executeStep = () => {
    //some steps
}
```

Comment: When I use it, I get this error
```
Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
```
I have this function inside a class which is being called in the index.js file

Comment: if you add this on class, you can use it without variable

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include [babel-transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)

In your example, you'll need to:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties
```

After successfully installation you need to modify your loader

```
{
   test: /\.js$/,
   loader: 'babel-loader',
   exclude: /node_modules/,
   query: {
      presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'react-hmre'],
      plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
   }
}
```

Using above my problem was solved. Bellow mention threads are very usefull to me solve this issue in my project.

[Source One](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-arrow-functions)
[Source Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063854/arrow-function-syntax-not-working-with-webpack)